# C++ program for checking a string for balanced ()s, {}s and []s

Tags: c++, brackets, parentheses, curly-braces

So here's my problem:

I'm supposed to write a c++ program that checks a string to be balanced. So far I have the code working to make sure that it has the same number of ('s and )'s (the same with ['s and {'s). The problem is that this works for almost everything, but it doesn't work for strings where the {'s, ('s and ['s all get mixed up.

For example: "{ { [ ( ) ] } ( ) }" comes back as balanced (true) as it should. However, "{ ( [ ] } )" comes back true, but it shouldn't.

What are some ideas in the logic and/or code that would check for when they're out of order?

Thanks for any help!

In case it helps, my code follows:

```
bool ExpressionManager::isBalanced(string expression)
{
//remove whitespace
string edited;
for(int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++)
{
    if(expression[i] == ' ')
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        edited += expression[i];
    }
}
expression = edited;

//set up brckets 
string brackets;

for(int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++)
{
    if (expression.at(i)=='(')
    {
        brackets += expression.at(i);
    }
    if (expression.at(i)=='[')
    {
        brackets += expression.at(i);
    }
    if (expression.at(i)=='{')
    {
        brackets += expression.at(i);
    }
    if (expression.at(i)=='}')
    {
        brackets += expression.at(i);
    }
    if (expression.at(i)==']')
    {
        brackets += expression.at(i);
    }
    if (expression.at(i)==')')
    {
        brackets += expression.at(i);
    }
}

int parenbal = 0;
int brackbal = 0;
int mustachebal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<(brackets.size());i++)
    {

        if(brackets[i]=='(')
            parenbal++;
        if(brackets[i]=='[')
            brackbal++;
        if(brackets[i]=='{')
            mustachebal++;

        if(brackets[i]==')')
            parenbal--;
        if(brackets[i]==']')
            brackbal--;
        if(brackets[i]=='}')
            mustachebal--;
    }

    bool isbalanced = false;

    if ((mustachebal==0)&&(brackbal==0)&&(parenbal==0))
    {
        isbalanced = true;
    }

    //check for brackets mixed up with other stuff.


return isbalanced;
}
```

Comment: Hint:  Use a stack data structure (e.g. `std::stack<char>`).

Comment: Another hint: imagine you were allowed to walk back and forth along the string, erasing characters when you chose...

Answer (score 5):

If you employ a [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) to store those tokens, then you are always looking for the closing-counterpart corresponding to the one on the top of the stack or an open-token.

The flow would be

- If the token is an open token, push it onto the stack.
- If the token is a close token, check if the top of the stack is the corresponding open-token. If it is, then pop the stack as you found them balanced. If it is not, then it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a homework assignment. So I would comment accordingly and allow you to learn a few things.

1. Always initialize your variables. strings are not initialized in your code.
2. You do not iterate over the string three time, you can check the string only once.
3. Use if-else if-else structure instead of if-if-if structure.
4. Always use brackets braces
5. Be consistent with your usage, either use at() or [], but dont mix them in code.

Comment: A default constructed `std::string` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this code may help you check string for balanced brackets with no
//repeated brackets,paranthesis or braces (e.g. [2*{3/(1+2)}].Note: no repeatance of
//brackets
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "IntStack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    char bracket[20];
    gets (bracket);
    char arr[6];
    int i=0;
    while(i<20)
    {
        switch(bracket[i])
            {
                case '[':
                {
                    arr[0]=1;
                    break;
                }
                case '{':
                {
                    arr[1]=2;
                    break;
                }
                case '(':
                {
                    arr[2]=3;
                    break;
                }
                case ')':
                {
                    arr[3]=3;
                    break;
                }
                case '}':
                {
                    arr[4]=2;
                    break;
                }
                case ']':
                {
                    arr[5]=1;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    cout<<"";
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(arr[3]==arr[2])
        cout<<"";
    else
        cout<<" ) or ( is missing "<<endl;

    if(arr[1]==arr[4])
        cout<<"";
    else
        cout<<" } or { is missing "<<endl;

    if(arr[5]==arr[0])
        cout<<"";
    else
        cout<<" ] or [ is missing"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void check_brackets (string bituy) 
{
    int flag = 1

    int count[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    stack<char> barstack;

    for (int i = 0; i < bituy.length(); i++)
    {
        if (bituy[i] == '{')
            count[0]++;
        else if (bituy[i] == '}')
            count[1]++;
        else if (bituy[i] == '(')
            count[2]++;
        else if (bituy[i] == ')')
            count[3]++;
        else if (bituy[i] == '[')
            count[4]++;
        else if (bituy[i] == ']')
            count[5]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 2)
    {
        if (count[i] != count[i+1])
        {
            cout << "Wrong Syntax!" << endl;
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bituy.length(); i++)
        {
            if (bituy[i] == '{' || bituy[i] == '(' || bituy[i] == '[')
                barstack.push(bituy[i]);
            else
            {
                if ((barstack.top() == '{' && bituy[i] == '}') || (barstack.top() == '(' && bituy[i] == ')') || (barstack.top() == '[' && bituy[i] == ']'))
                    barstack.pop();
                else
                {
                    cout << "Wrong Syntax!" << endl;
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag)
        cout << "No Errors!" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool isBalance(char n[],int size){
    int i,count=0;
    //int size=strlen(n);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(n[i]=='{'||n[i]=='['||n[i]=='('){
            count ++;
           }
           else if(n[i]=='}'||n[i]==']'||n[i]==')'){
            count --;
           }
           else return -1;
    }
    if(count==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
int main(){
    char n[1000];
    gets(n);
    int size=strlen(n);
    bool result=isBalance(n,size);
    if(result==true)
        cout<<"Balance";
    else
        cout<<"Not Balance";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that for the example in the post (`{ ( [ ] } )`)? Looks like your code doesn't deal with that issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
//bracket Chaecker program

void bracket_checker()
{
    int i=0;
    char d;
    char ch;
    int count=0;
    char *s = new char[21];

    fstream out;
    out.open("brace.txt",ios::in);
    while(out>>d)
        {
                if(d =='}'|| d ==')' || d == '{' || d =='(')
                {
                s[i]=d;
                i++;
                }
        }

    if (i % 2 != 0)
    cout <<"\ninvalid braces";

    else if (( s[0] == '}' || s[0]==')' || s[0]==']') || (s[i]=='{' || s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' ))
    cout <<"\n invalid braces";

    else
    {
        for(int a=0; a<i; a++)
        {

                if (s[a] == '(' || s[a] == '{' || s[a] =='[' )
                push1(s[a]);
                if((s[a]=='(' && (s[a+1]=='{' || s[a+1]=='}')) || (s[a]=='[' && (s[a+1]=='{' || s[a+1]=='}')))
                break;
                else
                if (s[a] == ')' || s[a] == '}' )
                {
                        if (head != NULL)
                    {
                        ch = pop1();
                        if( ch == '{' && s[a] == '}' || ch == '(' && s[a] == ')' || ch=='[' && s[a]==']')
                        cout <<" ";
                        else
                        break;
                    }
                else
                break;
                }
        }
                if(head==NULL)
                    cout <<" valid";

                else 
                    cout <<"In Valid";
    }


}
```